# Show shipping amount on orders table in the backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I'm wondering how can I show the shipping amount on the backend orders table.

I've already installed some extensions for grid customization but none of it has the option.

I've already found some articles explaining how to create columns on the backend and how to to make a join query to get certain values from the database but any of these articles were specific about the shipping amount value.

If someone could help me on that I'll really aprecciate! Thanks.

**After Rakesh Suggestion**

```
<?php

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                array('order'=>'sales_flat_order'),"order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id",
                array("shipping_amount"=>'order.shipping_amount'))->group("main_table.entity_id");
            $this->_collection = $collection;
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_amount', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping charge'),
                'index' => 'shipping_amount',
            ),'shipping_name');

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add Shipping Amount you have to join `sales_flat_order` table with current `sales_flat_order_grid` table.

Here is the code for add Shipping Amount

First need to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`

edit your module's `config.xml` and add this xml code.

```
<blocks>
  <ordergrid>
    <class>Rk_OrderGrid_Block</class>
  </ordergrid>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Rk_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

after that create `Rk/OrderGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php` file and below code.

```
class Rk_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
    {
        public function setCollection($collection)
        {
            $collection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                array('order'=>'sales_flat_order'),"order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id",
                array("shipping_amount"=>'order.shipping_amount'))->group("main_table.entity_id");
            $this->_collection = $collection;
        }
         protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
             $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_amount', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping charge'),
                'index' => 'shipping_amount',
            ),'shipping_name');
            return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }
    }
```

It will add `Shipping Amount` column after `Ship to Name` column.

**Rename `Rk_OrderGrid` with your module name.**

**UPDATE**

replace your `_prepareCollection()` function with this

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()
                   ->join(
                array('order'=>'sales_flat_order'),"order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id",
                array("shipping_amount"=>'order.shipping_amount'))->group("main_table.entity_id");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Comment: Rakesh, instead create a module is it possible to only copy Grid.php from /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/ to /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/ ?

Comment: I've tried to only copy the Grid.php to a local pool. The column was created but no data was filled there.

Comment: I have updated my answer please try that.

Comment: Rakesh, the column still empty. Is there a way to debug it ?

Comment: add this line  echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); before $this->setCollection($collection); and fire that sql query in database and check if you get shipping amount or not.

Comment: I'll vote your answer because it worked on another magento store. Sure this istallation have some bug I'll have to fix it. Thanks for you patience!

Comment: Thanks if it's works on another magento then you.can accept the answer so it is helpful for another user.